# Robocopy command to transfer files starting with "MY"

Tags: robocopy

My source folder has many text files with different names. I only want to transfer text files that starts with "MY" only.

For example: MY123.txt

How can I filter out those files to send to destination folder using robocopy? My current query as shown below.

```
robocopy "user\log" "D:\user\log2\files" /MAXAGE:20210401
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
robocopy "user\log" "D:\user\log2\files" "MY*" /MAXAGE:20210401
```

source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and [here](https://support.4it.com.au/article/robocopy-wildcard-examples/)